# C++ - functors vs classes

Tags: c++, class, functor

So, I've found out recently about functors in C++. If I understand it right, its a structure with a function. Now I know that they are useful because you don't need as much hardcoding, but I've been thinking, are they really that neccessary when you have classes?

So, a couple of questions I want to ask:

1. What are the differences between functor and class? (obv. without class { and struct { )
2. Is there anything you can't do with class, what you can do with a functor?
3. Is functor really all that neccessary?

Comment: A functor **is** a class.

Comment: A functor is a class with an `operator()` which allows instances of it to be called with function call syntax.

Comment: So why to call it functor then?

Comment: Because not all classes can be called like a function. It is a class of class :) Functors are classes, classes are not necessarily functors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: A functor *is* a class/struct. One with operator() defined.

2: n/a

3: nothing is really all that necessary. A function can't carry state, and if state is needed it must be juggled by parameters and work around lifetime of those. Functor comes handy when you need state and can hold it in the struct.

Comment: A functor use internal fields to store its state. What makes it different from a class which define the operator () ? Furthermore the same work can be done by both the operator() or a generic method (I can make a regular class method which execute the same functor instructions): For instance classObject() might be equivalent to classObject.method(). So the question arise again ...is a functor really needed ? Or is it just a different syntax for calling a method and saving the "classObject." prefix ?